# extract time from date without any format

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I want to extract just time from today's date

```
So date: 2018-09-26 12:08:29.930
required: 12082993 (HHMMSSSS) format
```

my query:

```
declare @time datetime = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108))
select format(@time,'hh\mm\ss')
```

Any help?!

Comment: FYI Formatting is usually considered a front end concern, not to be done in the query (if it can be avoided).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(time, GETDATE()), 'hhmmssff')
```

Time: 2018-09-26 17:29:04.920

Result: 17290492

Answer (score 0):

use **DATEPART()** function with **concat**

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEPART(HOUR, GETDATE()), DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE()),DATEPART(SECOND, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped!